# During page load, when does Firefox autofill / autocomplete forms?

Tags: javascript, firefox, forms, firefox3.6

I'm troubleshooting a weird bug with a web app prototype and knowing when, precisely, Firefox autofills / autocompletes form fields would be useful. I have a small specialized audience and only need to target Firefox 3.6+. For this question, there is no server interaction beyond initial page load.

This question is just about the order of operations during page load & reload since 1. that's really useful information and 2. concerted searching didn't turn up any answers (or even hints).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can intervene in this process.
But if you want to prevent this you need to set the autocomplete attribute to off:

```
<input autocomplete="off"... />
```

Comment: Thanks Mic; I don't need to intervene, though, I just need to know *what* happens *when* so I can work out the right answer. We need the form autofill and preserve-on-reload functionality to work "as expected". I sincerely hope this is a deterministic process.